# How to do moving Rorschach using Perlin noise in c# without shaders?

Tags: unity, c#, perlin-noise

I want to be able to make a moving Rorschach using Perlin noise like in [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102779/rorschach-ink-blot-aka-psychology-test-pictures-shader) question but I know nothing about shaders. Is there a way to do it in just c#?

Comment: You can by following the explanation in the answer you linked.  Just do it in C# instead.  Generate Perlin Noise, add a gradient to give a nice clean pattern.  Then mirror a section of the noise.   

What noise library are you using to generate your perlin noise?

Comment: Right Im just using the perlin noise in unity. What does it mean by add a gradient? Also what does it mean by directly threshold.

Comment: @Jon I understand what a gradient is but how do I add one to Mathf.PerlinNoise(x,y)?

Comment: @DMGregory could you please help?

Comment: You can't add gradient very easy to the Noise in Unity, unless you write it yourself.  It isn't that difficult, you would simply ADD or MULTIPLY the noise patterns together.  Your main issue is actually generating the gradient noise data, which Unity doesn't do.   Anyways, you should look into the Accidental Noise Library, to help you do this, or some other noise library system that you could use.  This will allow you to generate interesting noise patterns and blend multiple noise patterns together.

Comment: Ok so Im starting to think I don't know what a gradient is. Once I have my noise what do I do to it? Im using LibNoise in c#.

Comment: Gradient is just a noise pattern type.   It can look like a gradient when you render the data on screen.  This gradient can be whatever you define really.  Have a look here:  http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/minecraftworlds.html   And a usage example here (Generating Heat Maps)  http://www.jgallant.com/procedurally-generating-wrapping-world-maps-in-unity-csharp-part-3/#heatmap

Comment: @ReeceGrillett — looks like tagging users' names only works if they've posted in the thread previously. I didn't see this until just now. You're always welcome to ping me on Twitter if you want (@D_M_Gregory). Jon is right that you already have everything you need, but if I get time today I'll break it down into steps. Just note that doing this CPU-side is going to be vastly slower than in a shader. Is "no shaders" really a requirement, or do you just need some help working with shaders for the first time?

Comment: @DMGregory Well this function is only really for a few seconds of my current project, its for the title screen so I thought I could skip on learning how to use shaders. Ive gotten a good turbulence function going on but Im still stuck on making a gradient.

Comment: @DMGregory What do you think about the cpu usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think trying to do this with the CPU is just way more work than it's worth. This is the kind of texture operation GPUs were made to simplify & accelerate for us.

[image: Animated Rorschach Texture Example]

This animation was created using this shader code:

```
Shader "Unlit/Rorschach"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BlackLevel("Black Level", Range(0, 1)) = 0.27
        _Contrast("Contrast", float) = 60
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            // Most of this is boilerplate Unity creates for us
            // when we create a new shader. I removed the fog stuff...
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            // ...and added these variables to tune the blobbiness:
            float _BlackLevel;
            float _Contrast;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

                // Convert texture coordinates into range [-1, 1].
                // This makes our symmetry calculations neater.
                o.uv = v.uv * 2.0f - 1.0f;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float2 mirrored = abs(i.uv);
                // Mirror the x direction to get the classic symmetrical look,
                // and multiply by texture scale so we can handle rectangular quads.
                float2 uv = float2(mirrored.x, i.uv.y) * _MainTex_ST.xy;

                // These arbitrary magic numbers just scroll two samples of the noise texture
                // at different scales/directions/offsets so it doesn't look too regular.
                // Changing these values will change the movement speed/direction/blobbiness.
                float noise = tex2D(_MainTex, 0.3f * uv + _Time.x * float2(0.2f, 0.1f)).r
                    * tex2D(_MainTex, uv + _Time.x * float2(-0.3f, -0.1f) + float2(0.2f, 0.3f)).r;

                // Calculate a gradient that's brightest at the edges, to feather out the blob.
                float mask = max(mirrored.x, mirrored.y);
                mask *= mask * mask * _BlackLevel;

                // Threshold the sum to get the desired blobbiness.
                return saturate((noise + mask - _BlackLevel) * _Contrast);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, right-click in Project browser and select New -> Shader, then paste this code in. Then select New -> Material and choose the Rorschach shader from the dropdown (Under Unlit/Rorschach). Slap that material on a Quad and you'll be able to preview the effect live in the editor.

Assign a tiling noise texture as the texture ([I borrowed the noise used in this procedural cloud tutorial](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_clouds.htm)) and play with the `Texture Scale`, `Black Level`, and `Contrast` parameters until you get the look you want.

You can do this CPU side with a big array of `Color32` objects, replicating the math above (using your turbulence functions instead of the `tex2D` samples) in a loop, and then using [Texture2D.SetPixels32()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html) but I think it's likely to be both messier to code AND slower to run.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, and it appears to be straight forward. You need to create perlin noise then apply a filter that would take that noise and if its below a certain threshold return black, otherwise return white. Then you can invert the image along the x and y axes to get the "rorshasch" look.

The actual implementation is beyond the scope of the site, so heres a link to a pure written c# algorithm for the noise.

https://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/perlin-noise-in-c/

Filtering the output and then inverting it along the axes ought be easy enough to work out on your own.

Wikipedia also has a perfectly servicable pseudocode implementation that could be easily ported.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

edit: The page you linked had a link to this: http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/perlin/ within is the original c implementation of perlin noise which is about as canonical as you get!

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please describe the solution.

Comment: Im not sure what explaination you'd need beyond that? Explaining perlin noise is beyond the scope of gamedev stackexchange, and the links provided give an implementation.

Comment: The OP did not ask "how does perlin noise work?", and when the sites go offlane, this answer provides no use.