# How is this smoke effect made?

Tags: particles, pixel-art

In the game `Sheepy`, first (actually second) boss is a crazy cat that generates a very cool kind of light/smoke effect, as it is visible in this video at 12'00:

https://youtu.be/BKBfftWn5Zo?t=720

It looks like some particle effect with additive blend (+ pixelization) mixed with manual animation of the cat in pixel art. The engine seems to be Construct3 if that helps.

Is this how it's done? Else what could be the techniques used?

**EDIT**

- The cat is animated frame by frame.
- It *looks like* that the smoke is a solid surface with a flower-shaped sprite particle that keeps being generated from the particle emitter but I am still not sure that this is how it is made.

Comment: I'd say this looks like it"s generated with a noise function, modulated by an expanding wedge shape (possibly a particle ribbon). Take a look at the [scrolling noise texture approach at the bottom of this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/102786/39518) for an example of how complex that can look with relatively simple inputs, and it looks chaotic and fluid in motion.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the link. I see that perlin noise is used, this seems to help with the randomness of the effect.

Comment: @evilmandarine I checked out the assets for the game and the cat is indeed frame-by-frame animated by using a spritesheet that contains each frame of the animation. The smoke effect however I couldn't seem to find in the assets, so it might be procedurally generated. There is some light textures present in the assets so I'm thinking that the smoke is generated, which is then rendered together with some lighting to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0):

The smoke effect might simply be an elaborate frame-by-frame animation parented to the cat, rather than a procedural effect. I haven't played Sheepy, but given the very fluid frame animation of the cat when it jumps on and climbs around the elevator, it seems safe to assume that a similar technique was used for the smoke.

If this is indeed a frame animation, it may be composed of multiple layers, and possibly broken into tiles.

Eventually, someone will probably rip the art assets from the game, and then you'll have a concrete answer.

Comment: I think the cat is definitely frame by frame but I doubt it is the same for the smoke (at least for the second part, but maybe the initial explosion is also frame by frame indeed).

Comment: I have very strong doubts the smoke is a frame by frame animation. Amount of data would be ridiculous for just a few frames and you can quite clearly see the motion of the particles.

Comment: @DirkBoer The amount of data might be ridiculous if it was hundreds of 4k frames encoded as separate textures, but there are many ways to encode frame animations that use up far less data (such as video formats like h.264). Large effects can also be made up of tiles. I have no idea what you mean by "quite clearly see the motion of the particles"; it's one large continuous effect.

Comment: Anyway, if Daniel_1985's comment on the OP is accurate, my theory was wrong. DMGregory's answer of perlin noise is probably correct; that was actually my first thought, but I started thinking about frame animation after seeing the level of detail of the cat's animation.

Comment: Oh, and on the amount of data - even it was a series of non-tiling textures, the front layer wouldn't need to be 4k because it's pixelated. It could be much lower-res and scaled up with nearest-neighbor scaling.

Comment: I think its fairly unlikely to be a frame by frame animation. As Daniel_1985 said, he couldn't find it in the game files. I think its more likely to be procedurally generated, its probably not that hard to check though, just play the effect in the game twice, and see if its exactly the same, or different.

Answer (score -1):

**Note for the downvoters: of course I mean realtime and in shaders, not in Photoshop - thats just a 3 minute mockup to make it visual**. If thats not the reason for the downvote please explain yourself.

I think my attempt would be a like a 2D particle metaballs in a secondary buffer.

Gradients from white to black, set to additive and animate that:

[image]

After that in a post process effect on that layer put a "levels  / range":

[image]

And between maybe add some edge noise. Like throw a blocky noise map over the whole image before you set the levels.

[image]

After levels/range:

[image]

Then take this as a mask, and draw it once purple/lighten for the highlight and once dark/black for the main sligthly offset.

[image]

There also seems to be a general glow posteffect on their screen that really blends it together.

Of course this needs a lot of tweaking, but I would roughly take this approach.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. I don't think this is how it's done but I appreciate the effort and idea.

Comment: Downvoting and no comment. Probably by someone who never did vfx. What makes you think they didn’t do a similar approach?

Comment: @DirkBoer I downvoted because the smoke effect in the video is clearly not made up of individual particles, your process would have a high performance cost, and your final example frame looks nothing like the effect in the game (even if it's rough). I do VFX all the time in Unity, including particle effects and hand-written shaders.

Comment: The effect looks good but is quite different from the one in the video.

Comment: @DirkBoer This type of hostile and personal reaction is why I sometimes don't leave a comment when downvoting. Note that my explanation of the downvote is only focused on the content I see in your answer; I'm not attacking you personally or questioning your credentials. Likewise, I know my own level of skill and experience and don't feel the need to try to personally impress you with my showreel.

Comment: @Kevin fair enough. I've deleted my comments, because I agree it is too hostile. I do think your tone of voice and way of downvoting is really negative. Why would you demotivate other people to answer? Nothing to learn for anyone?